# Making a Corpus out of Wiki DumpFile using Python in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, wikipedia, corpus

I am trying to create a corpus out of Wiki DumpFile.

I've downloaded the Wiki enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 file, but when I run the code(script) it gives me some errors.

I am relatively new to this, but I do not understand how the python code and the wiki file should be placed (same folders, which folder, etc.).

I've run this command: `make_wiki_corpus enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 wiki_en.txt`

- `make_wiki_corpus` - being my python script
- `enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2` - is the wikipedia database
- `wiki_en.txt` - the textfile I want to write into.

```
import sys
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

def make_corpus(in_f, out_f):

    """Convert Wikipedia xml dump file to text corpus"""

    output = open(out_f, 'w')
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)

    i = 0
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
        i = i + 1
        if (i % 10000 == 0):
            print('Processed ' + str(i) + ' articles')
    output.close()
    print('Processing complete!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print('Usage: python make_wiki_corpus.py <wikipedia_dump_file> <processed_text_file>')
        sys.exit(1)
    in_f = sys.argv[1]
    out_f = sys.argv[2]
    make_corpus(in_f, out_f)
```

I ran the command, containing this code, being in the same file with the enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2  file, but at the command prompt I get some error messages like:

```
line 636 in \__init__  
line 92 in __init__  
FileNotFound Eroor : [Errorno21] No such file or directory "enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"
```

Comment: You should put the path_to_file from your prompt directory.

Comment: Sorry @OSainz I don't quite understand what you are trying to say :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of these ideas would be useful for u (hopefully):

*suggestion #1*: if I'm not mistaken `python make_wiki_corpus {your bz2 file} {your txt file}` should be used;

*suggestion #2*: try to apply the whole directory path to your needed file;

*suggestion #3*: u could also print the code from the development environment itself (to avoid any complications possibly).